# RAM detection issue on 32-bit OS

Tags: c++, winapi, ram, windows

I want to detect memory using `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` function, the problem is, it only displays `RAM` correctly on 64-bit OS. On 32-bit OS I get wrong values. For example like in the picture below:

**On Virtual machine (Windows Vista SP2 x32):**

[image]

**Code:**

```
ULONGLONG ramSize;
BOOL result = GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(&ramSize);

if (result == TRUE) {
    QString ramMB = QString::number(ramSize / (1024.0));
    QString ramGB = QString::number(ceil(ramSize / (1024.0 * 1024.0)));
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Test_MB", ramMB.append(" MB")); // RAM in MB
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Test_GB", ramGB.append(" GB")); // RAM in GB
}
```

Why it doesn't work on 32-bit OS? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this on a physical box?  Could be a VM BIOS issue, I see in the docs - The GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory function retrieves the amount of physically installed RAM from the computer's SMBIOS firmware tables. This can differ from the amount reported by the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function, which sets the ullTotalPhys member of the MEMORYSTATUSEX structure to the amount of physical memory that is available for the operating system to use.

Comment: Define "wrong". What should it be instead? Are you aware of the limitations of a 32-bit system? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: To eliminate any presentational issues, try `printf("%I64u\n",ramSize);`. This is unlikely, because you cast to double before calling QString::number, but it is good to check.

Comment: @dsolimano

Maybe the problem with VM BIOS. I don't have a machine with x32 OS to test it on real hardware.

Comment: @Cobra91151 actually I don't either anymore . . . Does anyone?  Might not be worth worrying about any more than you worry about Windows 2000 compat.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition

It should be 2048 MB (2 GB). Yes, I know about limitation on 32-bit OS.

Comment: You say Virtual Machine. What technology are you using? Loads of details missed out of this question.

Comment: First result on Google for `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory 32-bit wrong virtual` is now this page lol fml

Comment: I use VMware Workstation and I tried from Vista to 8.1 (x32 - x64). Issue is only with x32. Can someone test it on real hardware. Thanks.

Comment: @user877329

Thanks. I will try it and reply.

Comment: @user877329 

I have test it. The same issue is still present. The only thing is to test it on real hardware or check for `GetLastError` to get more info.

Comment: So, just to be absolutely sure, you are claiming that `ramSize` is actually being set to 6047196160 and not to 2097152 as expected, is that right? Are you getting a similar bad `ullTotalPhys` value from [`GetMemoryStatusEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589.aspx) as well?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau

From `ullTotalPhys` value `GetMemoryStatusEx()` I get 2047 MB (2 GB). So the values are correct, but from `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()` it is wrong.

Comment: @Cobra91151: then you should report this as a bug to the vendor of your VM system.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau

How do you know exactly that this is a bug in VMware Workstation? Did you test it on 32-bit OS?

Comment: @Cobra91151: No, I did not. Since "*The `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` function retrieves the amount of physically installed RAM from the **computer's SMBIOS firmware tables***", and VMware implements the BIOS that Windows is querying, it stands to reason that this is a VMWare bug.  See [SMBIOS Support in Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20110903164158/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463136) for how to access the SMBIOS data yourself, maybe you can check if the underlying data is actually wrong or if `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()` is just misinterpreting it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau

Ok. Thanks. I will try it. Also I'm thinking about installing Win 7 x32 as a second OS to test it on real hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Windows 7 x32 and test it. Now the values are correct. So the bug is with VMware Workstation. I will report it to VMware later. Thanks all for help.